# Dask DataFrame to_parquet return bytes instead of writing to file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parquet, dask, fastparquet

Is it possible to write dask/pandas DataFrame to parquet and than return bytes string? I know that is not possible with `to_parquet()` function which accepts file path. Maybe, you have some other ways to do it. If there is no possibility to do something like this, is it makes sense to add such functionality? Ideally, it should be like this:

```
parquet_bytes = df.to_parquet() # bytes string is returned
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been work undertaken to allow such a thing, but it's not currently a one-line thing like you suggest.

Firstly, if you have data which can fit in memory, you can use fastparquet's `write()` method, and supply an `open=` argument. This must be a function that creates a file-like object in binary-write mode, in your case a `BytesIO()` would do.

To make this work directly with dask, you could make use of [the MemoryFileSystem](https://github.com/martindurant/filesystem_spec/blob/master/fsspec/implementations/memory.py) from the filesystem_spec project. You would need to add the class to Dask and write as following:

```
dask.bytes.core._filesystems['memory']  = fsspec.implementations.memory.MemoryFileSystem
df.to_parquet('memory://name.parquet')
```

When done, `MemoryFileSystem.store`, which is a class attribute, will contain keys that are like filenames, and values which are BytesIO objects containing data.

Comment: (note, I don't know whether pyarrow would be able to write directly to a BytesIO)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe has a single Pandas dataframe inside (one partition), you can write it to a temp directory and read those bytes:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
    df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(data, npartitions=1)
    df.to_parquet(Path(tmp), write_index=False, schema=None)
    parquet_bytes = Path(tmp, "part.0.parquet").read_bytes()
```